# vagrant cannot find ansible on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: python, ansible, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a new MacBook running OS Monterey and I'm trying to install a project in vagrant.
I have a completely clean install of the OS and I've downloaded the resources from GitHub. I previously had an identical copy running on an old machine.
I installed ansible locally using the recommended

```bash
python3 -m pip install --user ansible
```

`pip3 show ansible` tells me that `ansible 5.2.0` is installed in `/Users/this_user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages`

When I run `vagrant up` vagrant imports the Virtualbox `bento/ubuntu-20.04` but when it gets to provisioning it fails, first with

```
vagrant gathered an unknown Ansible version
```

And falls back on compatibility mode `1.8`

And then:

```
The Ansible software could not be found!
```

I tried the suggestion of adding `/Users/this_user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages` to `$PATH` but this did not solve the problem.

```
ansible --version` results in `ansible: command not found
```

I'm running the latest `Vagrant, 2.2.19`.

Comment: What is the output of `ansible --version` and what is the version of vagrant your are running ? Please don't answer in comments, edit your question.

Comment: My guess: either ansible is reporting it's version strangely... or you need to upgrade vagrant so that it reads correctly version reported by ansible-core > 2.10. In this later case, downgrading ansble to version <= 2.10 could also do the trick. See https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-vagrant-examples/issues/83

Comment: In addition to the other fine suggestions, I'll point out that `site-packages` is **not** the correct directory to add to your `$PATH`, it's almost certainly `$HOME/Library/Python/3.8/bin` based on your other examples, although `dirname $(command -v ansible)` will tell you for sure. Good luck with your question that belongs on https://SuperUser.com/ since it is about general software and not programming

Comment: @mdaniel - Thanks for your suggestion about SuperUser.com. I will certainly try over there.

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled with `python3 -m pip install ansible`
then installed with Homebrew, `brew install ansible`
This solved the problem.

Comment: 1) This probably solved your problem by installing an older version of ansible. I you are aware of that and that's exactly what you want that's fine. But getting an up-to-date vagrant was probably wiser in that case  2) The question and self-answer are absolute duplicates of [the ones you posted on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1699914/vagrant-cannot-find-ansible-on-mac-os-monterey). Please do not cross post questions and answers over stackexchange sites. Choose the appropriate one and stick to it. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator - thanks. I appreciate your comment on duplicating questions. Another user commented that the question should really be on SuperUser. Although I posted there, in hindsight, I think here is the correct site.

Comment: I personally think the good site was superUser. But you should understand the comment from mdaniel as an insight to transfer your question there (i.e. delete here + post there) rather than duplicating it. Meanwhile, welcome ;)

Comment: @Zeitounator - regarding point 1, vagrant is the latest (2.2.19) and ansible --version tells me [core 2.12.1], also up-to-date.

Comment: @Zeitounator - regards deleting here, then posting there - Thanks, I will do that should the situation arise.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Virtualenv** solved my problem :

I uninstalled ansible :

```
python3 -m pip install ansible
```

Create virtualenv :

```
virtualenv myenv -p python3
source myenv/bin/activate
```

Then install ansible :

```
pip3 install ansible
```